# Get checked radio table data value when change the div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here I am append table element after ajax success response and its working good and the code is ...

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '{{ route("shipping_address") }}',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          data: myData,
          success: function(data) {
                var x=data['rates'];
                var table = '<table class="rates"><tr><th>Providers</th><th>Days</th><th>Price</th></tr>'
                $.each(data['rates'], function (key, val) {
                  table +=  '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="shipment_radio" id="shipment_radio"></td><td id="providers">'+val.provider+'</td><td id="days">'+val.days+'</td><td id="amount">'+val.amount+'</td></tr>'                 
               });
               table += '</table>';
               var result = $('#shipping').append(table);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
          }
    });
```

It append inside the div which is in html element

```
<div id="shipping">
</div>
```

I want to get the checked table value which  means when i click the first radio button i want that table data price then i check second radio i want that table price..
I try this

```
 $(document).on('change', '#shipment_radio' ,function() {
      $('.rates').removeClass("checked");
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass("checked");
      var price = $('.checked').find('td#days').text();
      alert(price);
        });
```

But i didnot get the correct result

How to achieve this...PLease help me

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
$.each(data['rates'], function (key, val) {
    table +=  '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="shipment_radio" id="shipment_radio"></td><td id="providers">'+val.provider+'</td><td id="days">'+val.days+'</td><td id="amount">'+val.amount+'</td></tr>'                 
});
```

here you are using `shipment_radio` as `ID`, but its occurrence are more than one. So instead of `ID` use `Class` selector like:

```
class="shipment_radio"
```

and add event listener to it:

```
$(document).on('change', '.shipment_radio' ,function() {
```

Comment: when i change in to class first time i click the radio it shows the first table value second time i click it shows first and second value

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be having a unique id, so instead of id make use of class since you are looping over it.

```
 $.each(data['rates'], function (key, val) {
              table +=  '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="shipment_radio" class="shipment_radio"></td><td class="providers">'+val.provider+'</td><td class="days">'+val.days+'</td><td class="amount">'+val.amount+'</td></tr>'                 
           });
```

and then you can get he required result by getting the next `td` with `class days` from the parent of the radio ie. a `td` element. Also `closest` is a better option than using multiple `parent` functions

```
$(document).on('change', '.shipment_radio' ,function() {
      $('.rates').removeClass("checked");
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("checked");
      var price = $(this).parent().next('.days').text();
      alert(price);
});
```

Comment: Did you change everyting to class

Comment: Can you `console.log($(this).parent())` and see if you ge the td element and then debug for next('.days')

Comment: yes i am getting like this `[td, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: input.shipment_radio]` in my console

Comment: Then check the  `$(this).parent().next('.days')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146019/discussion-between-karthiga-and-shubham-khatri).

Answer (score 0):

You are create element with duplicate identifiers which make HTML invalid as Identifiers in HTML must be **unique**

Use common classes to bind  event handler

```
 $.each(data['rates'], function (key, val) {
     table +=  '<tr><td><input type="radio" name="shipment_radio" class="shipment_radio"></td><td class="providers">'+val.provider+'</td><td class="days">'+val.days+'</td><td class="amount">'+val.amount+'</td></tr>'                 
 });
```

Then you can DOM relationship to traverse and target them

```
$(document).on('change', '.shipment_radio' ,function() {
    $('.rates').removeClass("checked");
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.addClass("checked");
    var price = tr .find('.days').text();
    console.log(price);
});
```